# Как отсортировать коллекцию по алфавиту в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Как отсортировать коллекцию в Laravel в алфавитном порядке (от А до Z)?

Сейчас код выглядит следующим образом:

```
$cities = usort(Cities::all()->toArray(), fn($a, $b) => $a['name'] <=> $b['name']);
```

Результатом выполнения кода является ошибка: Only variables should be passed by reference. Если создать дополнительную, новую переменную, куда будет складываться результат выполнения этой сортировки, то всё нормально. В чём причина такого поведения?

Comment: в том, что `usort` получает массив по ссылке и изменяет его, ничего не возвращая. Вы же передаете туда результат вызова функции. В результате чего собственно итог работы будет утерян. Передавать надо ссылку на переменную-массив, это написано в тексте ошибки. иное по ссылке нельзя передавать.

Comment: @teran спасибо за ответ. Функция usort возвращает boolean, а в остальном, да, вы полностью правы. Этот момент я по какой-то непонятной для себя причины проглядел... Уже со всем разобрался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если вам надо отсортировать уже полученную коллекцию, воспользуйтесь методом `sortBy`:

```
Cities::all()->sortBy('name');
```

2. Вы также можете отсортировать данные на стороне Sql, воспользовавшись методом `orderBy`:

```
Cities::orderBy('name')->get();
```